# Does the equivalence of nonlinear (especially exponential $f(u^2)=f(x^2)$) functions denotes equality of variables $(u=x)$, for given constraints?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions, exponentiation

I have a function given as $f(x^2)$ and the same function with some different variables $f(u^2)$, **the constraint is both x and u are positive numbers.** The function is given to be composed of square roots but **nothing** like floor or ceiling functions where the inversion of variable may lead to several different values in the domain.
Can I then say that
$$x=u$$ if $$f(x^2)=f(u^2)$$
Also, suppose now the function is given as $f(x^n)=f(u^n)$ where $n$ is positive integer, with the same constraints, then will $x=u$?

**Also, If the condition $f(x^2)=f(u^2)$ does not guarntee equality what empirical/numerical methods I can use to check if both $x=u$, because plotting for different values will result in overlapping curves.**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What if $f$ is a constant function? If that's not possible, please be more precise about what kind of function $f$ can/can't be.